# Optimize a query with ordering by columns on different tables

Tags: postgresql

I have this query, and it is extremely slow:

```
SELECT a.id,
COALESCE(uas.read, CAST(0 AS BOOLEAN)) as read,
COALESCE(at.link, '') as thumbnail_link
FROM users_feeds uf INNER JOIN articles a
    ON uf.feed_id = a.feed_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_articles_states uas
    ON a.id = uas.article_id AND uf.user_login = uas.user_login
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles_thumbnails at
    ON a.id = at.article_id
WHERE uf.user_login = 'test1'
ORDER BY uas.read, a.date DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

It takes on average 500ms to complete with my current set of data. The two biggest tables are 'articles' and 'users_articles_states', both holding roughly 100000 records each.

If I drop the 'uas.read' from the ORDER BY, the query executes in roughly 2ms. Both the 'read' and 'date' columns from both of these tables have indexes (which I guess would explain why it is so fast when only sorting by date)

The query plan for the slow execution is as follows (after vacuuming):

```
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=27944.57..27944.69 rows=50 width=104) (actual time=321.465..321.471 rows=50 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=27944.57..28218.93 rows=109747 width=104) (actual time=321.464..321.465 rows=50 loops=1)
         Sort Key: uas.read, a.date
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 34kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3863.32..24298.85 rows=109747 width=104) (actual time=45.736..292.656 rows=92297 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (a.id = at.article_id)
               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3668.47..23088.83 rows=109747 width=17) (actual time=44.205..235.573 rows=92297 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((uf.user_login = uas.user_login) AND (a.id = uas.article_id))
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.57..14331.50 rows=109747 width=24) (actual time=0.019..73.701 rows=92297 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (a.feed_id = uf.feed_id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on articles a  (cost=0.00..12757.64 rows=94964 width=20) (actual time=0.003..34.462 rows=93916 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.31..1.31 rows=21 width=12) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=21 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on users_feeds uf  (cost=0.00..1.31 rows=21 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.009 rows=21 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (user_login = 'test1'::text)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                     ->  Hash  (cost=1741.65..1741.65 rows=92283 width=17) (actual time=44.170..44.170 rows=92282 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 639kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on users_articles_states uas  (cost=0.00..1741.65 rows=92283 width=17) (actual time=0.005..24.293 rows=92282 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (user_login = 'test1'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 10
               ->  Hash  (cost=135.49..135.49 rows=4749 width=95) (actual time=1.520..1.520 rows=4733 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 606kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on articles_thumbnails at  (cost=0.00..135.49 rows=4749 width=95) (actual time=0.004..0.765 rows=4733 loops=1)
```

The index on 'read' is : "users_articles_states_read_idx" btree (read)

I'm guessing that psql can't use this index. Is there any other index I can create so that things are fetched relatively fast, or any other way I can change the query itself to appease the db?

EDIT 1: I mistakenly posted the original query with an error (INNER JOIN on the 'uas' table)

Table definitions:

```
readeef=> \d users_articles_states
 Table "public.users_articles_states"
   Column   |  Type   |   Modifiers   
------------+---------+---------------
 user_login | text    | not null
 article_id | bigint  | not null
 read       | boolean | default false
 favorite   | boolean | default false
Indexes:
    "users_articles_states_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_login, article_id)
    "users_articles_states_read_idx" btree (read)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_articles_states_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "users_articles_states_user_login_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_login) REFERENCES users(login) ON DELETE CASCADE


readeef=> \d articles             
                                    Table "public.articles"
   Column    |           Type           |                       Modifiers                       
-------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                   | not null default nextval('articles_id_seq'::regclass)
 feed_id     | integer                  | 
 link        | text                     | 
 title       | text                     | 
 description | text                     | 
 date        | timestamp with time zone | 
 guid        | text                     | 
Indexes:
    "articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "articles_feed_id_guid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (feed_id, guid)
    "articles_feed_id_link_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (feed_id, link)
    "articles_date_idx" btree (date)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "articles_feed_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feed_id) REFERENCES feeds(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "articles_extracts" CONSTRAINT "articles_extracts_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "articles_scores" CONSTRAINT "articles_scores_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "articles_thumbnails" CONSTRAINT "articles_thumbnails_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "users_articles_states" CONSTRAINT "users_articles_states_article_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

EDIT 2:
Adding an index to 'user_login' doesn't remove the Seq Scan, probably because there are only a few 'users' in the db.

EDIT 3: Forgot to mention, psql version is 9.3.9

EDIT 4: I tried something a bit different. I removed the 'uas.read' from the ORDER BY clause, and added " AND uas.read = 't'" to the WHERE one. The execution time was 0.4ms according to the planner. When changing the later to " AND uas.read = 'f'", the execution time jumped to 622ms. There's literally no difference between the two execution plans, beside the costs, the filter (one being NOT read, the other read), and the 'rows removed by join filter':

```
                                                                                QUERY PLAN (slow query)                                                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.99..2374.08 rows=50 width=103) (actual time=0.064..671.332 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.99..50263.02 rows=1059 width=103) (actual time=0.063..671.330 rows=2 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..49930.39 rows=1059 width=17) (actual time=0.057..671.319 rows=2 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..47995.18 rows=3744 width=48) (actual time=0.039..363.354 rows=92052 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (uf.feed_id = a.feed_id)
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1873485 (1207 in fast one)
                     ->  Index Scan Backward using articles_date_idx on articles a  (cost=0.29..46589.91 rows=93597 width=20) (actual time=0.011..58.529 rows=93597 loops=1) (rows=60 in fast one)
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.32 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=21 loops=93597) (loops=60 in fast one)
                           ->  Seq Scan on users_feeds uf  (cost=0.00..1.31 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.013 rows=21 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (user_login = 'test1'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 4
               ->  Index Scan using users_articles_states_pkey on users_articles_states uas  (cost=0.42..0.51 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=92052)
                 Index Cond: ((user_login = 'test1'::text) AND (article_id = a.id))
                 Filter: (NOT read) (read in fast one)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
     ->  Index Scan using articles_thumbnails_pkey on articles_thumbnails at  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=1 loops=2)
           Index Cond: (a.id = article_id)
```

After testing with the same data and similar scheme in sqlite3, it is as slow when ordering by 'uas.read', but it has no problem filtering by it in the WHERE clause. It's the same ~0.5ms execution time regardless of whether its ' AND NOT uas.read' or ' AND uas.read'

Comment: uas.read is a boolean column ? [note: please add the table definitions, etc]

Comment: try to use with as to enhance the performance

Comment: An index on uas.read alone is probably not so useful, as you need two join columns as well. Can you try an index on `(read, user_login, article_id)`. If `read` really is a boolean columns, an index will not help too much probably. And do you really need to order then (instead of having `WHERE READ = true`)? Aren't you in effect still only ordering on the second column (because the first 5000 rows will all have the same value for `read`). That would be very hard on the database (especially as that second order column comes from a different table).

Comment: You may want to try indexes on users_articles_states(user_login) and users_feeds(user_login). Both of these are doing sequential scans in this plan.

Comment: @RobDiMarco: True. But "rows removed by filter" is almost nothing. Which does seem weirdly skewed, too. Is there only one user in this database?

Comment: Might also be a good idea to denormalize a bit and put a copy of `date` into `uas`. Then you can sort/filter on both columns in a single index. Same for other small and immutable article meta-data that you want to work with.

Comment: I think that I would try an index on articles(feed_id, date desc), and users_articles_states (user_login, read), and hope to get a join from users_feeds to users_articles_states, and then to articles. That's the only way I can see of being able to use the indexes. It might make it more clear that that is the intent if you reorder the FROM clause also, for the purpose of humans reading it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Adding the indexes and reordering the FROM doesn't do anything in terms of changing the execution time or plan